# Target array elements using forEach

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

This function multiplies array numbers with their neighbor and returns the largest product. I tried making this function using forEach, but I couldn't get the inputArray[i + 1] to work. How can I target an array elements neighbor in a forEach? Thanks!

```
function adjacentElementsProduct(inputArray) {
  var product = inputArray[0] * inputArray[1];
  for(var i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
    if((inputArray[i] * inputArray[i + 1]) > product) {
      product = inputArray[i] * inputArray[i + 1];
    }
  }
  console.log(product);
}
```

Comment: Your last iteration checks an index beyond the input array, but the reason your function still works is because `NaN > anything` is `false`

Answer (score 1):

You could take a copy of the given array, starting by the second element with [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and iterate over that array. Then take the product of the same index of the iterating array and the original array for a product. Compare and update `product` if necessary.

How it works:

> ```
> index       0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7 
> original [  1,  3,  5,  3,  7,  4,  8,  2  ]
> copy     [  3,  5,  3,  7,  4,  8,  2  ]
> product     3  15  15  21  28  32  16
> ```

```js
function adjacentElementsProduct(inputArray) {
    var product = inputArray[0] * inputArray[1];
    inputArray.slice(1).forEach(function (a, i) {
        var p = inputArray[i] * a;
        if (p > product) {
            product = p;
        }
    });
    console.log(product);
}

adjacentElementsProduct([1, 3, 5, 3, 7, 4, 8, 2]);
```

The same with [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
function adjacentElementsProduct(array) {
    return array.slice(1).reduce(function (r, a, i) {
        var p = array[i] * a;
        return r >= p ? r : p;
    }, undefined);
}

console.log(adjacentElementsProduct([1, 3, 5, 3, 7, 4, 8, 2]));
console.log(adjacentElementsProduct([-1, 1]));
console.log(adjacentElementsProduct([0, 0]));
console.log(adjacentElementsProduct([42]));
console.log(adjacentElementsProduct([]));
```

Comment: .slice().forEach() is an interesting way to do this. Thanks!

Comment: The reduce version gives incorrect result with `[-1, 1]`.

Answer (score 0):

[foreach](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_forEach.asp) arguments provide current index and array object. There is no way to directly get next value in arguments.

```
inputArray.forEach(function(currentValue, index, array){
    product = currentValue * array[index+1]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As described in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), the foreach callback function takes 3 parameters :

- the element value
- the element index
- the array being traversed

so you can access to the next item like that:

```
myArray.forEach(function(value, index, array) {
  product = value * array[index + 1];
}
```

I let you complete your code to get the higher product ;)

Comment: ... and when you're in the last iteration, `array[index + 1]` is `undefined`. That was the OP's problem.

Comment: The question was _How can I target an array elements neighbor in a forEach?_  I answer to the question but i let him finish the implementation ;)

Comment: That last iteration was coming up as NaN.

Comment: Yes I know, i didn't say the opposite. I let him just discover that by himself. I just answer its question ... The goal was just to help him, not code for him

Answer (score 0):

[`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)'s callback function takes three parameters - the current item, the current index, and the array.

A conversion of your code to forEach would look like this:

```
function adjacentElementsProduct(inputArray) {
    let product = inputArray[0] * inputArray[1];
    inputArray.forEach((item, index, array) => {
        if (item * array[index + 1] > product) {
            product = item * array[index + 1];
        }
    });
    console.log(product);
}
```

In my opinion [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) is a better fit for this type of problem.

```
function adjacentElementsProduct(inputArray) {
    const result = inputArray.reduce((largestSoFar, current, index, array) => {
        const product = current * array[index + 1];
        return (largestSoFar === null || product > largestSoFar) ?
            product :
            largestSoFar;
    }, null);
    console.log(result);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Andy, I had forgotten that forEach has an index parameter. This answers my question.